# php mail with attachment and html

Tags: php, email, header, html-email

I have been trying to get mail to send html emails however it seems that whenever i change the header from
       $message .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; to
       $message .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

the email does not arrive.When using text/plain, i receive the email however the html is not rendered, in other words i received the code rather than formatted html. Changing to text/html, the email is not received at all. I have tried using UTF-8 but can not seem to solve it after hours of searching. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $emessage) {
$file = $path.$filename;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);

$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$message = "--".$uid."\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
//$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\""."\r\n";
//$message .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$message .= $emessage."\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; 
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$message .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$uid."--";
return mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
   }
```

Comment: Have you checked if it is going in to spam? Normally HTML emails are more likely to be caught by a spam filter.

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder? If your html is some what bad they go into spam

Comment: i feel like a complete idiot, yep there they all are